# How to rename thewire's URL in Elgg?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, elgg

I have an install of ELGG, and I set up thewire. I hate the name thewire so I modified the language file, so it would look like posts.

When I looked at the URL on the posts page, it still said `http://localhost/thewire`, not `http://localhost/posts`. How would I make .htaccess change the URL to the desired effect.

I tried mod_rewrite, but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Can post some more examples of original and new URLs

Comment: Modifying the language will have no effect on what URL is used. What does the contents of you current .htaccess file look like? i'm guessing there are already some modrewrites with elgg making clean URLs.

Comment: Elgg provides other ways of modifying entity URLs. Using mod_rewrite doesn't handle creation of the URL and creates unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

- Change the URLs produced for thewire posts (register your own handler):

  `elgg_register_entity_url_handler('object', 'thewire', 'CUSTOM_HANDLER');`
- Handle new URL format instead of original one:

You may use 'route' plugin hook or try to use already existing plugin for that: http://community.elgg.org/plugins/854839/1.1/pagehandler-hijack-18x